# How do I make the circle around my "i" perfectly circular?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a little info graphic with CSS so I have

```css
.info_icon {
  font-style: italic !important;
  color: #008EE2;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<i class="info_icon">i</i>
```

Maybe its just my screen (I'm on MacBook Pro), but the little circle around the "i" appears somewhat cut off on the left and the right.  I have an example here -- https://jsfiddle.net/w6e94dyp/ .  Does anyone know how to fix this (make the circle around the "i" perfectly circular)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box of the element needs to be a square (*equal width and height*). So instead of padding, set its `width`/`line-height` and center it horizontally.

```css
.info_icon {
  font-style: italic !important;
  color: #008EE2;

  display: inline-block;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff;
  background-color: #ccc;
  /*added the following and removed the padding*/
  text-align:center;
  width:1.5em;
  line-height:1.5em;
}
```

```html
<i class="info_icon">i</i>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using `border-radius: 50%` instead like this to fix cropping:

```css
.info_icon {
  font-style: italic !important;
  color: #008EE2;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #008EE2;
}
```

```html
<i class="info_icon">i</i>
```

But if you need a perfect circle you need to set the same `width` and `height` and give a similar padding for all four sides, like this:

```css
.info_icon {
  font-style: italic !important;
  color: #008EE2;
  padding: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #008EE2;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<i class="info_icon">i</i>
```

Comment: I agree as well with this, would be nice if tables were not so prominent, will make the responsive easier (if it is something you eventually wan to look into) but this is a better approach or one i would have used

Comment: This is wrong, the problem is not with the radius size (*100px provided is much more than the 50% in this case*). The problem is that the element is not square (same width/height) and so it does not become a circle but an oval.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Thanks for this comment, I updated the answer to solve the issue you mentioned.

Comment: @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni it's better to use em units in case the font-size property value changes, and you do not need to declare the height property along with line-height in this case.

Comment: @Ricky I totally agree that it is better to use em units, but this is only an example to fix a specific issue related to `border-radius`. And regarding adding the `i` as HTML instead pseudo-element is for clarity and readability only. Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

```
padding: 5px 13px;
```

Seems to work. You have to take into account the padding goes from the farthest part of the letter i, so horizontally will have to be significantly less than vertically.